# Is the Google Direction API for android is free of cost?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2, directions

I am developing an android app in which I will show the direction from one location to another I have integrated it with Google Maps. So, now I am trying to use google direction API and already generated API key for that but when I am using it by doing https request in my browser it showing me the result: **"Request denied"**

Below is the response I am getting in the result.
Is it necessary to enable Billing or I am doing it wrong?
Because I will not request for direction again and again in my app, I will just hit the web service once and will use that response in my app in which I will show 2,3 paths from only one origin to destination

```
{
  "error_message": "You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started",
  "routes": [],
  "status": "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

Comment: it's paid, according to the error that appears

Comment: Billing account is mandatory for Google Maps Platform. You have a free tier of $200 per month. So if your usage is less than $200 you won't pay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's required that you enable [Google Billing](https://console.cloud.google.com/billing) for some [Google API Services](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer), this doesn't mean that you will get charged for those services; most of them have a free quota and when you go beyond the threshold you get charged, and how much? well, it depends. For some API or services you can use [Google Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/) and for some others you need to check the product's page. For example for [Google Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/)

[image]

So you can use 60 minutes without any issue but it requires that you have enabled the [Google Billing](https://console.cloud.google.com/billing) to make it work.

For [Google Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/usage-and-billing) is:

[image]